# Toggle class on orientation change in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

How can we toggle class of an `element` based on orientation of device.

Example:

```html
<div class="landscape"></div>
```

```css
@media (orientation: portrait) {
.landscape: {...}
}
```

I can change `landscape` css properties. but I want to avoid this.

Instead, I would like to change the class itself thus, it would look like

```html
<div class="portrait"></div> // if orientation is portrait
<div class="landscape"></div> // if orientation is landscape
```

Any suggestions for this!

Note: Would accept answer for `vue` as well

Update: `screen.orientation` doesn't work on `safari`. solution should work on `safari` too.

thanks for your appretiatable answers.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: @PeterSH that's quite complex, wanted it to be simple as orientantion `portrait` or `landscape`. thanks for the link.

Comment: This is simpler: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation. Keep in mind that this has limited browser compatibility (especially mobile browsers)

Comment: @PeterSH you are right!, thats giving error on `safari` browser. Found the 
right solution, will post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this code using `matchMedia`. But maybe I made a mistake somewhere in this code. But the essence and structure are correct.

```
window.matchMedia('(orientation: portrait)').addListener(function(m) {
       let div_class = document.querySelector('.landscape');
       if (m.matches) {
                div_class.className = 'portrait';
            } else {
                div_class.className = 'landscape';
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function (event) {
  const { angle } = event.target.screen.orientation; // orientation angle
  let orientation = angle === 90 || angle === -90 ? "landscape" : "portrait";

  const element = document.getElementById("#customElement");
  
  element.classList.remove(['landscape', "portrait"]);
  element.classList.add(orientation);
});
```

Comment: ` screen.orientation` doesn't work on `safari` browser, my bad didn't mention it.

Comment: will, include a work around for this in my answer then

Comment: `orientationchange` is now a deprecated feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event

Answer (score 1):

a nice way to do this would be to give the element and id say "orient"
ALSO: safari doesn't use window.screen.orientation, but window.orientation

```
<div class="" id="orient"></div>
```

```
const orient = document.querySelector("#orient")

//add the current orientation as a class
if(!window.orentation){
    orient.classList.add(window.screen.orientation===0 ||  window.screen.orientation===180 ? "portrait":"landscape")
}else{
    orient.classList.add(window.orientation===0 ||  window.orientation===180 ? "portrait":"landscape") //for safari
}

//now check for when orientation changes and toggle on/off as required
//safari uses window.orientation instead :(
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", (e)=>{
        orient.classList=""; //empty class list
        if(!window.orientation){
            orient.classList.add(window.screen.orientation===0 || window.screen.orientation===180 ? "portrait":"landscape"); //add the correct value back
        }else{
            orient.classList.add(window.orientation===0 || window.orientation===180 ? "portrait":"landscape"); //for safari :(
        }
});
```

Comment: `screen.orientation` doesn't work on safari browser.

Comment: yes, but according to this post ```window.orientation``` does, http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-orientation/

Answer (score 1):

How I implemented, based on accepted solution.

```js
    window.matchMedia('(orientation: portrait)').addListener(function(event) {
      if (event.matches) {
        const landscapeClassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.landscape');
        landscapeClassElements.forEach(element => {
          element.classList.remove('landscape')
          element.classList.add('portrait')
        });
      } else {
        const portraitClassElements = document.querySelectorAll('.portrait');
        portraitClassElements.forEach(element => {
          element.classList.remove('portrait')
          element.classList.add('landscape')
        });
      }
    });
```

`matchMedia('(orientation: portrait)').matches` returns `true` for `portrait`

`window.matchMedia` is simple and works on `safari` as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to accomplish this!

```css
.portrait { display: none; }
.landscape { display: block; }

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .portrait { display: block; }
  .landscape { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: op says he's trying to avoid rewriting the landscape class styling. javascript might be best

Comment: @TochiBedford yes, want to toggle class , this answer wont help